# Logit function steepness and midpoint

Tags: functions

From [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function) on the Logistic function, I understand that this is a "special case" of the [Sigmoid function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function). And I believe the inverse of that function is the [Logit function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logit).

I am unfortunately a math newbie, and I wasn't able to figure out how to introduce the parameters that the Logistic function has into the Logit function. Specifically, I want to be able to change $x_0$ (the x-value of the sigmoid's midpoint) and $k$ (the steepness of the curve), in the same way I can do that in the Logistic function:

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{1 + e^{-k(x-x_0)}}$$

How can I introduce those variables back into the Logit function?